# Test if iptables would pass a given ip/ip-range

Tags: iptables, testing

I am currently trying to debug problems relating to our firewall configuration and found myself in the situation where I would like to test a config.
Ideally I would like to take the iptables config and give it an IP or an IP range and get the decision iptables is going to make.
i.e.

```
>> my-iptables-test /etc/sysconfig/iptables 54.91.251.226
Action: DROP
```

or something similar. I had a look for existing solutions, but I was not able to find anything. Probably just searching for the wrong words.

Just to be clear: I do not have access to the machines I would like to test, so "telnet" from that machine is not available. The iptables config is also sufficiently long to get lost.

Comment: Giving it just an IP address wouldn't be enough as the rules can consider a lot of other things than just the IP address.